# Connection timeout when trying to connect to server on project

Tags: c#, kotlin, .net-core

I am trying to connect through a socket in kotlin and the program responds with an exeption from timeout and I think i have opened the portand it is actually the same port I have opened before... so what could I do be doing wrong?
client

```
    val client = Socket("192.168.250.4", 4646)
    client.outputStream.write("Text".toByteArray())
    println(client.isConnected)
    client.close()
```

server

```cs
            listenerTask = new Task(async()=>await StartListening(port));
            listenerTask.Start();
        
        async Task StartListening(int port)
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
            tcpListener.Start();
            while(!tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(async () =>
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = string.Concat(richTextBox1.Text, "Listening Port:" + port, "\n");
                }));
                await Task.Run(async() => { tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); });
            }
            Invoke(new Action(async () =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = string.Concat(richTextBox1.Text, "Listening Port:" + port, "\n","Connected","\n");
            }));
        }
```

Comment: What exception do you see?

Comment: @HughW Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect